# iOS Charts: Determine the positioning and color of the highlighted entry

Tags: ios-charts

I have a pie chart implemented with the [Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). Now when an entry is tapped and becomes highlighted, I would like to show a tooltip that shows the value of the selected entry, positioned in the middle of the entry, and outlined in the same color of the selected piece of the pie.

In the delegate function `chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)` I can obtain the highlight's `xPx` and `yPx`, but this is the touch point where the user tapped to highlight this entry, not the center point of the entry itself, so centering the tooltip on these values results in the tooltip jumping around depending on where you tap the entry. And I don't see any way to get the color of the highlighted entry.

I am trying to obtain the following, and outline it in that pink color:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**:: 1 :: Position of the Popup**

Hmm... I've been looking and I don't think the `ChartDataEntry` has an available `frame` to use as a reference point for setting your popup's position.

I think doing it based on the tap location is a decent alternative, though. That at least gets the popup to show in the same general region as the pie segment. It should still be a good user experience, in my opinion. :)

**:: 2 :: Color of the Currently Selected Segment**

`PieChartDataSet` has a `values` property that has your `ChartDataEntry` objects in it. So you could find the index of the matching one since the `chartValueSelected` delegate method passes you the current `ChartDataEntry` object (`entry`).

Answer (score 0):

`PieChartView` has the `marker` property which you can use for display marker when a value is clicked on the chart. In my opinion, using `marker` property and creating the custom marker class it is a preferred way of resolving your task.

The custom marker class must conform to `IMarker` protocol and can be instantiated from `MarkerImage` class. Pay attention to two functions:

- `draw(context: CGContext, point: CGPoint)` function with two input params which pass position and context for drawing. So you have information about the position for your balloon.
- `refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)`. In this function, you can choose a color for the balloon. `MarkerImage` class has `chartView` property so you have access to datasets. If you use more than one dataset, you can use a value of `highlight.dataSetIndex` to define dataset which was clicked. When the dataset is chosen you can get a color from `dataSet.colors` property using index obtained by `dataSet.entryIndex(entry: entry)`.

Example of color choosing:

```swift
open override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)
{
    let dataSet = chartView!.data!.dataSets[highlight.dataSetIndex]
    let colorIndex = dataSet.entryIndex(entry: entry) % dataSet.colors.count
    color = dataSet.colors[colorIndex]

    super.refreshContent(entry: entry, highlight: highlight)
}
```